# Java - error: cannot find symbol - Mesmo com objeto criado

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, java-ee, jdbc

Eu criei estas duas classes:

Equipamento.java

```
class Equipamento{

  private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String local;

  public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setNome(String n){
    this.nome = n;
  }
  public void setLocal(String l){
    this.local = l;
  }

  public int getId(){
    return this.id;
  }

  public String getNome(){
    return this.nome;
  }
  public String getLocal(){
    return this.local;
  }

}
```

JDBCComandos.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

class JDBCComandos{
  private static Connection con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();

  public static void Create(String nome, String local){
    String sql = "insert into equipamento (nome,local) values (?,?)";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, nome);
      ps.setString(2, local);
      ps.execute();
      ps.close();
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }

  public static List<Equipamento> Retorna(){
    List <Equipamento> Componentes = new ArrayList <Equipamento> ();
    String sql = "select * from equipamento";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next()) {
        Equipamento e = new Equipamento();
        e.setId(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("equip_id"))  );
        e.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
        e.setLocal(rs.getString("local"));
        Componentes.add(e);
      }
      rs.close();
      ps.close();
      return Componentes;
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }

  public static void Update(int id, String nome, String local){
    String sql = "update equipamento set nome = ?, local = ? where equip_id = ?";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, nome);
      ps.setString(2, local);
      ps.setInt(3, id);
      ps.execute();
      ps.close();
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }

  public static void Delete(int id){
    String sql = "delete from equipamento where equip_id = ?";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setInt(1, id);
      ps.execute();
      ps.close();
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }

  public static List<Equipamento> retornaEspecifico(String nome, String local){
    List <Equipamento> Componentes = new ArrayList <Equipamento> ();
    String sql = "select * from equipamento where nome like ? and local like ?";
    try{
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, "%" + nome + "%");
      ps.setString(2, "%" + local + "%");
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next()) {
        Equipamento e = new Equipamento();
        e.setId(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("equip_id"))  );
        e.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
        e.setLocal(rs.getString("local"));
        Componentes.add(e);
      }
      rs.close();
      ps.close();
      return Componentes;
    }catch(SQLException erro_sql){
      throw new RuntimeException(erro_sql);
    }
  }
}
```

Eu fiz um teste na seguinte classe, e tudo funcionou perfeitamente:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

class MainTest{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    JDBCComandos jdbc = new JDBCComandos();
    //jdbc.Create("Teste novo", "Novo Teste");
    for(Equipamento c : jdbc.Retorna()){
      System.out.print(c.getId() + " ");
      System.out.print(c.getNome() + " ");
      System.out.print(c.getLocal() + "\n");

    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    for(Equipamento c : jdbc.retornaEspecifico("este n" , "este")){
      System.out.print(c.getId() + " ");
      System.out.print(c.getNome() + " ");
      System.out.print(c.getLocal() + "\n");

    }
  }
}
```

O problema foi quando eu tentei compilar essa classe:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

class ListEquipamento extends HttpServlet {
  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        JDBCComandos jdbc = new JDBCComandos();

        System.out.println("<table style=\"width:100%\">");
        for(Equipamento c : jdbc.Retorna()){
          System.out.println("<tr>");
          System.out.print("<th>" + c.getId() + "</th>");
          System.out.print("<th>" + c.getNome() + "</th>");
          System.out.print("<th>" + c.getLocal() + "</th>");
          System.out.println("</tr>");
        }
        System.out.println("</table>");

    }

}
```

Eu recebi o seguinte erro:

```
ListEquipamento.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        JDBCComandos jdbc = new JDBCComandos();
        ^
  symbol:   class JDBCComandos
  location: class ListEquipamento
ListEquipamento.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        JDBCComandos jdbc = new JDBCComandos();
                                ^
  symbol:   class JDBCComandos
  location: class ListEquipamento
ListEquipamento.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        for(Equipamento c : jdbc.Retorna()){
            ^
  symbol:   class Equipamento
  location: class ListEquipamento
3 errors
```

Por que isso está acontecendo sendo que todas estão exatamente na mesma pasta e a classe MainTest não tem problemas em encontrar as classes?

Comment: Aparenta se um problema de referência, Tem certeza que todos os imports estão certos?

Comment: @Lucas Eu verifiquei os imports, não vi nada de errado com eles. Acho improvavel ser um problema de referencia porque eu chamei os objetos da mesma forma na classe MainTest, e funcionou. Esse deveria funcionar também pq estão todos na mesma pasta. Depois do Seu comentário eu pesquisei exemplos de Servlets e JDBC na mesma classe pra ver se teria alguma diferença, mas não tem...

Answer (score -1):

Tenta colocar as classes como public. Como vc não definiu nenhum modificador de acesso ao declarar a class, por default o java coloca ele como friendly.

No momento não tenho como te dizer se impacta, mas vale a pena fazer um teste.